# How can I validate a database output value in SoftwareAG Webmethods

Tags: jdbc, webmethods

Hi I'm new to SoftwareAG Webmethods, I'm calling a jdbc adapter service and getting the result, based on result I have to validate and suppurate the values and give them as input to another flows. So how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by validate? Checking that a result was returned from the DB, checking the values for correctness, checking the number of items?

Comment: Thanks @HenningWaack my requirement is checking the number of items and correctness Ex table have 3 columns data,we are retrieving the data,and checking how many records are there and Is all are have the valid data or not. If valid go to the one sequence else go to the another(default) sequence.

Comment: Ashok, webMethods IntegrationServer offers all kind of data validation and manipulation capabilities. So you can loop over the data, count the number of records, do all kinds of validation. And of course you can split the data and pass it on to other services. Your question is still too unspecific for me to give you a more helpful answer, sorry. I think you should try to learn the basics first of the programming paradigm of IntegrationServer, and then you can post specific questions.

Comment: Thanks @HenningWaack I have solved the problem and it's working fine. Testing also completed. Anyway thanks for your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

depending what you want to achieve you can:

1. use some build-in service pub.list:sizeOfList for checking result size
2. checking using BRANCH'es (with option evaluate labels='True' like picture is showing.
3. You have some many option provided by webmethods, if you need something more complex java service is good choice.

[image: branch]